# Avoid blocking mysql and PC with mysqldump

Tags: mysql

I have a root access to a mysql server, I need to dump ALL the database inside the server.
I tried with a simple mysqldump, but the server and pc seems blocked due to the large size of the databases and tables. Can I "optimize" this DUMP avoiding locking the server (and PC) ?

Thank you so much!

**EDIT:**

I want to EXPORT all the databases from a Mysql Server.
I need to understand what options to pass to mysqldump to avoid blocking:

1. The Mysql Server <---- it **CAN'T** go down
2. The PC that is goind to do this DUMP

Answer (score 0):

Fire the dump command from commandline. :

```
mysqldump <other mysqldump options> --routines > outputfile.sql
```

If we want to backup ONLY the stored procedures and triggers and not the mysql tables and data then we should run something like:

```
mysqldump --routines --no-create-info --no-data --no-create-db --skip-opt <database> > outputfile.sql
```

If you need to import them to another db/server you will have to run something like:

```
mysql <database> < outputfile.sql
```

Comment: wonk0 , read carefully. He wants all the database inside server. Means he wants to import something. He never said that I want to disable locking. Cancel your down vote. And who says that bigdump quality is questionable?

Comment: I read carefully, thank you very much. The OP has problems using mysqldump, which is for *creating* a dump, not for inserting it. And about the quality of bigdump - well, I say so.

Comment: Question by Dail : " I need to dump ALL the database inside the server" . Means he wants to import, NOT EXPORT. and Mysqldump is used to both import and export, my friend.

Comment: No I want to EXPORT all the database inside the server. Excuse me If i wrote wrong

Comment: That is called import. If i am not wrong you have one or many large sql files. and you want to create relevant database/tables in mysql server? right?

Comment: NO, I want to read all the databases and save them inside .sql file (or files)

Comment: Then you should have written that you need to dump in a file not in server. anyway i just post another answer.

Comment: @Ravi I saw the edit, but the problem is that doing commands likes those block the server because it manage very big databases. What are the complete options i can pass to mysqldump to "optimize" this DUMP (into a file) ?

Comment: The mysqldump client is a backup program originally written by Igor Romanenko. It can be used to dump a database or a collection of databases for backup or transfer to another SQL server (from: man mysqldump). Please show me how to use mysqldump to IMPORT data into a database.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable locking:

```
mysqldump --skip-lock-tables
```

Of course you will not be able to create a consistent dump that way, so I would not recommend to use that option.

When only using MyISAM and ARCHIVE tables you might want to consider using mysqlhotcopy (included with a regular mysql package). There is similar software for other table engines like InnoDB available.

Another option is using a replication slave for backup.